# Is it ok to use “within” with “upon”?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

For example, is this sentence correct?

> The requested goods must be delivered within 5 business days upon receipt of a request (or simply upon request).

Comment: Yes, your sentence is okay. You are using "within" in one prepositional phrase, and "upon" for a second, different prepositional phrase. If you want to shorten your sentence, you could say, "The goods must be delivered within 5 business days of the request." Or "The goods must be delivered within 5 business day of receiving a request."

Comment: Mere proofreading questions are off-topic, per the FAQ.

Comment: Welcome, Pujing. Please can you edit your question to explain why you think you can't use *within* and *upon* like that? You might also found our proposal for a site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners) of interest.

Answer (score 3):

It is acceptable to say *upon*; *of* or *from* would be better.

The normal pattern is:

> within *[time period]* of / from *[event]*

E.g.:

> within 5 business days of receipt of request

To understand why *upon* is also acceptable, notice that we can also just say:

> within *[time period]*

E.g.:

> Goods must be delivered within 5 days.

When the *of* / *from* part of the structure is missing, the *[event]* must be inferred from context.  We can make that context explicit by adding an *upon* modifier to the beginning sentence:

> *Upon receipt of a request*, goods must be delivered within 5 days.

Or we can add it to the end of the sentence:

> Goods must be delivered within 5 days upon receipt of request.

So, to reiterate, *within ... upon ...* is acceptable, but *within ... of ...* and *within ... from ...* are preferable.